# Making another Local Branch with Egit

Tags: git, github, egit

My problem is with using github and Egit.  Egit fetched all of my repository branches and it had me select an initial branch which it then created a local copy of that branch.  I've been trying to make another local copy of one of the other remote branches, but have been unable to figure out how to do this.  So does anyone know how I can make a local branch version of another remote branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found if you right click on the remote branch, and tell it to branch, it will make a local copy of the remote branch.  I originally thought this would make a brand new branch from that branch, but it seems to just make a copy of the remote branch locally, which is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project and select `Branch...` in the `Team` menu. From there you'll be able to create a new local branch

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> Team -> Switch to -> New branch

This will create a local branch with Egit.